# CSS Works Fine Locally But Not on Wordpress Page

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to understand why some CSS isn't being friendly with me - I was messing with this codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/arcs/pen/OmZaex
```

When you enter information into the input, it has the label move up and out of the way.

I'm almost positive this line of CSS is doing the work:

```
#inputContainer input:valid + #inputLabel {   
top: -15px;   
font-size: 11px;   
font-weight: normal;   
color: #9e9e9e; 
}
```

I have never seen this convention before and when I try to use it on a Wordpress page, this CSS state is not being triggered.

CSSLint also declares this as invalid.

Any CSS experts out there know how to make this work on a Wordpress Page...or at least why it's not working?

**Edit: I failed to mention this was inside of a Wordpress Page - I apologize for forgetting probably the most important aspect of this question**

Comment: i dont think this has anything to do with godaddys server, but with your link to the css file (if its not inline with the file)

Comment: any javascript errors? How did you add css and js code?

Comment: It's all inline - I don't understand the use of selector IDs and the + sign...which is what fails.

Javascript is running w/ no errors - but the CSS does not get applied when I enter info into the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe issue with relative paths to your local environment vs. where they are on the server. Try changing the paths to your files to absolute/full paths based on server. Also, is any of the css formatting working? For example,

Relative Paths
    /files/style.css

Absolute Paths
    http://www.yoursite.com/files/style.css

Comment: It's all inline. 

The same exact file run on my local machine works - but the file on the server doesn't recognize that line of CSS